# Troubleshooting a problematic IPTABLE rule

Tags: fail2ban, ufw

### Background

I am very new to Fail2Ban, UFW, and IPTABLES. The rules in place on the VM in question, were mostly generated automatically. Some I added after following instructions for such. One is causing an issue.

The server environment is: Nginx, PHP7.1-fpm, Redis, PHP-FPM, MariaDB

### Problem

Running `sudo systemctl --status` I had two failed services.

```
hv-fcopy-daemon.service
netfilter-persistent.service
```

I am working on resolving the `netfilter-persistent.service` issues.

I run the following:

```
~$ sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4

   iptables-restore v1.6.0: Couldn't load target `f2b-sshd':No such file or directory
   Error occurred at line: 48
```

Line 48 is:

`-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd`

I see that nearly all the rules are generated via UFW (which was something I implemented), but there were some via F2B as that's what some of the automated VM deployment tools I used implemented.

If I remove that one rule line, the `iptables-restore` works fine.

My concern is that I have no idea if it's something that needs to be there, or not. My full set of rules are [here](https://codepad.co/snippet/J3rWbmy6).

### Question

1) Is that rule required, and if so, is it effectively handled by another rule (perhaps one of the port 22 related UFW rules)?

2) Are there any immediately obvious issues with the rules in use?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't attempt to use iptables-restore when also using UFW.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Okay. Thanks. So what would be an alternative way to figure out which iptable entry was causing the `netfilter-persistent.service` to fail to load?

Answer (score 0):

1. don't think so. it was generated by fail2ban and it will regenerated

if you're using a moderately recent version of fail2ban  why not use the ufw banaction ?

```
cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
$EDITOR /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

look for the line banaction=
and replace it with banaction=ufw

with that fail2ban will use ufw to block/unblock ips

Comment: Currently there's, `banaction = iptables-multiport`. So, by changing that to what you've suggested, this means if fail2ban is triggered to ban something, it will pass that over to UFW rules to handle? Am I understanding that correctly? Also, if I put `[sshd] enabled = false` will that prevent f2b from adding the `-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd` rule in my `rules.v4`? I am also wondering why that rule gets rejected.

Comment: with that it will ask ufw to block/unblock a specific IP (you can look inside /etc/fail2ban/action.d/ufw*).

puting [sshd] enabled = false will disable the jail, fail2ban will not monitor  log files for failed login attempts  (/var/log/auth.log in debian based systems). I.E sshd will not be protected by fail2ban.